# Pattern for iterating over chunks of a string to build a new string in C?

Tags: c

My question title isn't clear, sorry. I tried ;)

- I have a **binary** string that contains nul bytes.
- I know the length of the string.
- I have a function (from a library) encodes strings into another format.
- I need to encode the binary string using the library function.
- The library function **doesn't accept a length** & assumes the string is nul terminated.
- I know how to encode the nul bytes by hand (represent them as `"\\000"`)

Take the pseudo code:

```
/* I have a string, and the length in bytes of that string */
char * data   = value->bytes;
long   length = value->length;

/* I need to use a function, but it doesn't handle embedded nuls */
char * encoded = lib_func_encode(data);
lib_free(encoded); // library function requires a free() routine be called
```

That **doesn't work**, because the library function only encodes the first chunk of `data` up to the first nul byte. I could write a fairly horrible loop that keeps calling strlen() on `data` and counting until `length` bytes have been encoded, appending a `"\\0000"` string every time I need to encode some more bytes, realloc'ing some buffer to accomodate each extra chunk of encoded data. It feels like this is going to be a lot of code to get around a fairly simple problem. Coming from a language with concepts like `split()` (on the nul bytes) `map()` (to encode each chunk) and `join()` (using `"\\000"`) I'm instinctively thinking about the cleanest solution that way... but nothing really exists in standard C to do things like that.

In a fictional functional language it might look like:

```
join("\\000",
     map(lambda(chunk){encode(chunk)}, split('\0', data)))
```

How would a seasoned C programmer write a routine like I need to write?

Comment: Generally, using binary strings with functions accepting C strings is considered impossible, but here you are +1 for a good problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in multiple steps:

1. Find all embedded nul bytes
2. From this and the length you can calculate the length of a new string
3. Allocate a new string of the calculated length
4. Iterate over the binary string copying all non-nul characters, when reaching a nul character insert the special character sequence
5. Terminate new string
6. Call library function with new string
7. Free the new string

Comment: taken from steps:  "when reaching a nul character insert the special character sequence"... Yes, that's the first idea I have thought about. But you have to be sure, that the special character sequence won't be anywhere else in the whole string. How to achieve it? Binary string can contain any value in any order. Am I wrong?

Comment: @srnka If I read the OP correct, he wants to replace all `'\0'` characters in a string with the sequence `"\\000"`, without regards if the `'\0'` character exists multiple times in the source string.

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing you can do is to just `replace` the `null byte`s up to the the length excluding the last null(string terminator). once you replaced the `nulls` then you can do what you want with the replaced string.